# Creating a bitmap after rotating a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bitmap

I am trying to create a bitmap after rotating a view. The code i am using is:

```
                FrameLayout fl_imaging = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.fl_imaging);
                fl_imaging.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                fl_imaging.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap viewCapture = fl_imaging.getDrawingCache();
                String saved_at = Utils.saveImageOnDisk(Utils.imageName(), viewCapture);
                fl_imaging.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Now it creates a bitmap and i am able to save it as well. But the issue is it is not saving the bitmap with the rotated **fl_imaging** view. Please come up with your brilliant suggestions. Thanks

Comment: `the issue is it is not saving the bitmap with the rotated fl_imaging view`. Ok. What is so strange about that? The bitmap is only drawn rotated on the view. Not rotated itself i think. How did you rotate the view?

Comment: i am rotating view by fl_imaging.setRotated(value); in preview it rotates, but when i save it. Then it appears in its original orientation and rotation.

Comment: Yes. You already told that. We knew already.